Can we equate energy of photons to energy of EM waves by volumes?
I am trying to connect the wave model with the particle model of a beam of light through energy of a fixed volume in space.
By definition, the intensity is equal to power density $\left(\frac{J}{s \cdot m^2}\right)$ or $\left(\frac{W}{m^2}\right),$ and the power is equal to energy $E_t$ per unit time ($\frac{J}{s}$ or watt).
$$ 
I = \frac{P}{A} = \frac{E_t}{A\Delta t} \tag{1}.
$$
The intensity, in wave model, is the time average of the energy flux or the Poynting vector $S(x,t)$. The intensity of light moving at speed $c$ in vacuum is found to be
$$
I = <S(x,t)> = \frac{\epsilon_0 c E_0}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{E_0^2}{Z_0}\tag{2},
$$
where $E_0$ is the electric field amplitude, $c$ is the speed of light = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{ \mu_0 \cdot \epsilon_0}}$, and $Z_0$ is the EM wave impedance in the vacuum $Z_0= \sqrt\frac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_0}= 377\ \Omega$.
In particle model, the energy of photon is $E=h\nu$, so from Eq.(1), the total intensity for N photons is
$$
I = \frac{N \cdot h\nu}{A\Delta t}\tag{3}
$$
Since the intensity of two models should be the same, we have Eq.(2) = Eq.(3)
$$
E_t = N \cdot h\nu = \left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{E_0^2}{Z_0}\right){A\Delta t}=\left(\frac{\epsilon_0 E_0^2}{2}\right)(A \cdot c\Delta t)\tag{4}
$$
where $\left(\frac{\epsilon_0 E_0^2}{2}\right)$ represents energy density for the volume of $(A \cdot c\Delta t)$, where there are $N$ photons in it.
From equations (1) and (4), we have
$$
E_t  \propto N \propto I \propto E_0^2\tag{5}
$$
As an example, we assume we have a visible light wave with $\lambda =600 \mathrm{nm},$ $\nu=5\times10^{14}\mathrm{Hz},$ $A=(1 \mathrm{cm})^2$,  $\Delta t = 1 \ \mu \mathrm{s}$.
If $E_t = 1\ \mathrm{J}$ is given, we find it's $N=3.02\times10^{18},$ $\mathrm{Power} = 1\times10^{6} \mathrm{W}$, $I = 1\times10^{10} \mathrm{W}/m^2$ and $E_0 = 2.75\times 10^{6} \mathrm{V}/m$.
On the other hand, if  $I = 1\times10^{3} \mathrm{W}/m^2$ is given, we find it's $\mathrm{Power} = 1\times 10^{-1} \mathrm{W},$ $E_t = 1\times 10^{-7}\ \mathrm{J},$ $N=3.02\times 10^{11}$ and $E_0 = 8.68\times10^{2} \mathrm{V}/m$.
If we divide the 1st solution set with the 2nd one, we find Eq.(5) true with all the ratios = $1\times10^{7}$ except $E_0 \mathrm{ratio} = \sqrt{1\times10^{7}}=3.17\times10^{3}$.
Do you see any problems with this approach?

Without checking any of your numbers and formulas... there is no principle problem for classical waves and large photon numbers. You aren't gaining much in physical insight, though. At most it allows you to calculate photon statistics for applications like photography or astronomy. Beyond that it doesn't add anything to your understanding of light as a quantum phenomenon.

Your general idea is ok; your plugging in numbers seem to all be plucked from thin air, and since they are all derived from the same set, it is trivial to see that they would agree with the equation you had assumed to be true before you plugged in numbers.

$I = 1000 watts/{m^2}$ is the sunlight intensity. I got $E_t = 1 joule$ from online "So, there are approximately 2.52×1018 photons in a light wave with total energy of 1 J at a wavelength of 500 nm." I wanted to quantify the wave property of electric field to the particle property of photon.

The Hamiltonian of the EM wave is: $$H = \sum_{\vec k\alpha}\left(n_{\vec k\alpha} + \frac{1}{2}\right)\hbar\omega_{\vec k}$$
We can associate the number of photons to $n_{\vec k\alpha}$, the number of normal modes by frequency and polarization. So, the "count" should be made by frequency. For example, a high frequency with a certain macroscopic energy $E$ corresponds to some photons of high energy, while a low frequency (with the same $E$) corresponds to more photons of smaller energy.
See https://www.phys.ksu.edu/personal/wysin/notes/quantumEM.pdf

I agree that, for the same $E_t$, high frequency X-ray will make the photon count smaller than visible light's, see Eq.(4) $E_t = N \cdot h\nu$, even though the electric field and intensity remain same because they track with $E_t$, see Eq.(5). Somehow when we do time average of the Poynting vector for intensity in Eq.(2), the frequency disappeared.

Actually, the time average calculation is same as the root-mean-square calculation of V and I for an AC power on a circuit. If the circuit load is resistive, the RMS value is a constant $V_0/\sqrt 2$. The characteristic impedance of air $Z_0$ is resistive, so it is frequency-independent. Higher frequency will have more cycles within a fixed $\Delta t$, but the resultant energy remains the same because $power =V_0^2/2R$ and $energy = power * \Delta t$. The analogy between EM and circuit is V->E, I->B and V/I=R, E/B=c.
